# Proceed only when the file is copied fully .NET CORE

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, filestream, iformfile

I have a **web application** here.
The user uploads a .png file whos path I save in my database and copy the **IFormFile** to a different folder outside the application folder on my drive.

What happens is the file is getting created but its size is 0 bytes.

[zero_bytes.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHG8w.png)

My controller:

```
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage(Images file)
            {
                    file.is_deleted = "0";
                    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    string formattedDateTime = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    file.uploaded_on = formattedDateTime;
                    file.uploaded_by = GetUserName();
                    file.image_name = file.image_name.Replace(" ", "_");

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                            if (file.ImageUpload != null)
                            {
                                    string imageStorage = GetImageStorage();
                                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.image_name + ".png";
                                    imageStorage += fileName;
                                    var newFileStream = new FileStream(imageStorage, FileMode.Create);
                                    _ = file.ImageUpload.CopyToAsync(newFileStream);
                                    newFileStream.Close();
                                    file.image_path = fileName;
                            }
                    }
                    file.ImageUpload = null;
                    _ = kneoHttpClient.ApiPostResponse(ConfigAPI() + "Image/Add/", file);
                    file = null;
                    return View("Index");
            }
```

The data gets added to the database correctly so the copying is the only problem.

My HTML:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <img src="" id="default-image" />
        <input asp-for="ImageUpload" class="custom-file-input" id="myfile_input" required />
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="myfile_input" id="upload_image_button">Upload Image</label>
        <span asp-validation-for="ImageUpload" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Opening the image shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I9V7.png)

Thanks for the support!
Cheers!

I tried closing the fileStream as shown, it didnt work.
I tried clearing the file object but that too did not work.

Comment: You need to *await* the asynchronous copy operation: `await file.ImageUpload.CopyToAsync(newFileStream);`. You also need to create any streams in a `using` block to ensure they're closed when the method exits. Discarding responses just to silence warnings is *not* a good idea. The warnings are there to tell you about possible problems, like forgetting to await operations

Comment: Unless `kneoHttpClient.ApiPostResponse` is blocking, that needs to be awaited too. Otherwise `kneoHttpClient` may get disposed before it even had a chance to start making the remote call

Comment: The task returned by `file.ImageUpload.CopyToAsync` just gets deleted by `_`, thus it's finished just after starting, without having time to copy a single byte.

Comment: @SNBS no, it's not deleted, it's ignored. The actual `Task` object still exists but is orphaned and get disposed by the garbage collector once the request ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var newFileStream = new FileStream(imageStorage, FileMode.Create);
_ = file.ImageUpload.CopyToAsync(newFileStream);
newFileStream.Close();
```

to this

```
using(var newFileStream = new FileStream(imageStorage, FileMode.Create))
{ 
    await file.ImageUpload.CopyToAsync(newFileStream);
}
```

Asynchronous operations must be awaited, otherwise they might get discarded as soon as the request ends and the garbage collector cleans up any orphaned objects, like the Task returned by `CopyToAsync`.

Streams should be declared *inside* using blocks to ensure they get closed even if an exception occurs. `Stream.Dispose()` will call `Close()` internally